# Why do I keep seeing "Wireshark Cookie Dump Ok Cancel" in my input forms within Firefox?

Tags: firefox, wireshark

I've recently installed Wireshark on my Macbook Pro. Since doing so, whenever I head over to http://jsfiddle.net, all of the input fields are pre-populated with

> Wireshark Cookie Dump:
>
> OKCancel

So I went ahead and did a Google search for ["Wireshark Cookie Dump"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Wireshark%20Cookie%20Dump%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) and discovered thousands of results with the exact same problem at various sites across the internets.

Why on earth is this happening, and how can it be stopped?

FYI, I'm running Firefox 6.0.2 as my browser, and this doesn't seem to be happening in any of my other browsers (Safari, Opera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather from http://dustint.com/post/12/cookie-injection-using-greasemonkey, if you have the Greasemonkey user script Cookie Injector installed, you can use wireshark to dump a list of your cookies, and restore them with Cookie Injector; basically the form is asking you where you dumped the cookie list for that site. As for getting rid of it, it seems harmless enough. If you do still want to get rid of it, I would assume that getting rid of the Cookie Injector script would solve the problem, but if you don't have the script (or even Greasemonkey) installed, and you still get this issue, then I suggest asking at http://ask.wireshark.org/.

Comment: you are correct. simply disabling the injector script fixes the problem.